# Sequelize TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, database, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use sequelize model with an existing database in SQL Server. When I try to retrieve data from a table using raw query it works. But when I use a model I receive the follow error:

```
Error Occurred TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Function.findAll (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1692:47)
    at index (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\src\controllers\consulta_controller.js:7:39)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:110:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\Users\carlosli\Desktop\SigaWeb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

**Model:**

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class Consulta extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            seqConsulta: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                comment: "null",
                field: 'SEQ_CONSULTA'
            },
            descNickUsuario: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
                allowNull: false,
                comment: "null",
                field: 'DESC_NICK_USUARIO'
            },
            memConsulta: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(2048),
                allowNull: true,
                comment: "null",
                field: 'MEM_CONSULTA'
            },
            descConsulta: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
                allowNull: true,
                comment: "null",
                field: 'DESC_CONSULTA'
            }
        }, {
            sequelize,
            modelName: 'Consulta',
            tableName: 'CONSULTAS',
            freezeTableName: true
        })
    }
};
module.exports = Consulta;
```

**Controller**

```
const Consulta = require('../models/CONSULTAS');

module.exports = {
    async index(req, res) {
        let consulta
        try {
            consulta = await Consulta.findAll({
                where: {
                    seqConsulta: 1
                },
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error Occurred", e)
        }

        return res.json(consulta);
    },
};
```

Answer (score 24):

It happened the same to me and the problem was that I forgot to import my model in the database index, so maybe try something like this:

```
const Consulta = require('../app/models/Consulta ');
const models = [ Consulta ];
class Database {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.connection = new Sequelize(DataBaseConfig);

    models.map(model => model.init(this.connection));
}
}
```

Comment: Here to say my problem was also that I hadn't run `App.Database = new Sequelize({ args })`

Answer (score 1):

Just to let everyone know happend to me a different thing which was giving me back the same error.

This is my model class stored in /model/core-data/online-site/default-content-view.ts:

```
import { Model } from "sequelize";

export class DefaultContentView extends Model {
  ViewModelId: number | undefined;
  ContentTypeId: string | undefined;
  ViewId: number | undefined;
}
```

This is my db init function which as you can see was correctly pointing to my model class:

```
import { DefaultContentView } from "/models/core-data/online-site/default-content-view";

// Gets database instance
export async function initDb(database: string, user: string, password: string, host: string, port: number) : Promise<void> {
    // Gets connection properties from configuration
    const coreDb = new Sequelize(
        database,
        user,
        password,
        {
            host: host,
            port: port,
            dialect: 'mysql',
            query:{
                raw:true // this parameter makes sequelize to return only the model itself without the informations related to the instance
            }
        }
    );

    return coreDb.authenticate().then( () => {
        console.log('Connection estabished to Db');

        DefaultContentView.init({
            ViewModelId: {
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                field: 'view_model_id'
            },
            ContentTypeId: {
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: DataTypes.STRING(250),
                field: 'content_type_id'
            },
            ViewId: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                field: 'view_id'
            }
        }, { 
            timestamps: false,
            tableName: 'os_default_content_view', 
            sequelize: coreDb 
        });

    }).catch( () => {
        console.log('Unable to connect to Db');
    });
}
```

This is the service which was giving me the error when i was calling the list() function:

```
import { DefaultContentView } from "/models/core-data/online-site/default-Content-view";

    export class DefaultContentViewService {
    
      static list(): Promise<DefaultContentView[] | null> {
        return DefaultContentView.findAll();
      }
    }
```

Everything seems to be ok, not even one error but when calling the function it was continuously giving me back the error. I spent like 3 hours debugging and i figured out there was a wrong upper case 'C' in the model import in the service class (probably due to a replace), I changed "/models/core-data/online-site/**default-Content-view**" to "/models/core-data/online-site/**default-content-view**" and everything started working as expected.

I think this is because even if import is case insensitive in nodejs Sequelize takes care of it in a certain way.

I hope this helps saving time in debugging this kind of issues.