# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object (NestJS, Sequelize)

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs, typeerror

I'm having this issue with my NestJS app, where I just added a new module for a new feature I'm working on. We're using Postgres for DB, and other modules work fine. It's a system that's already in production. I have my model as shown below:

```
import {
  AllowNull,
  Column,
  DataType,
  Default,
  IsEmail,
  Model,
  PrimaryKey,
  Table,
  Unique,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { CinemaNameType } from 'src/types/cinemas.enum';
import { StateType } from 'src/types/states.enum';
import {
  PaymentStatusEnum,
  PaymentStatusType,
} from '../types/payment-status.type';
import { IEventHistory } from '../types/event-history.type';
import {
  BookingStatusEnum,
  BookingStatusType,
} from '../types/booking-status.type';
import { ICreateCubeBooking } from '../types/cube-booking.type';

@Table({
  paranoid: true,
  timestamps: true,
  underscored: false,
  tableName: 'cube_bookings',
  deletedAt: false,
})
export class CubeBookingModel extends Model<ICreateCubeBooking> {
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Unique
  @PrimaryKey
  @Default(DataType.UUIDV4)
  @Column(DataType.UUIDV4)
  id: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  state: StateType;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  cinema_id: number;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  cinema_name: CinemaNameType;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  movie: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.DATE)
  date_time: Date;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  guest_count: number;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  full_name: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @IsEmail
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  email: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Default(BookingStatusEnum.Pending)
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  status: BookingStatusType;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Default(PaymentStatusEnum.Unpaid)
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  payment_status: PaymentStatusType;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Default(0)
  @Column(DataType.FLOAT)
  payment_amount: number;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Default([])
  @Column(DataType.JSONB)
  events_history: IEventHistory[];
}
```

My service file:

```
import { Injectable, InternalServerErrorException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateCubeBookingDto } from '../dto/create-booking.dto';
import { UpdateCubeBookingDto } from '../dto/update-booking.dto';
import {
  BookingStatusEnum,
  BookingStatusType,
} from '../types/booking-status.type';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { CubeBookingModel } from '../models/cube-booking.model';
import { PaymentStatusType } from '../types/payment-status.type';

@Injectable()
export class CubeService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(CubeBookingModel)
    private readonly bookingModel: typeof CubeBookingModel,
  ) {}
  
  createBooking(bookingData: CreateCubeBookingDto) {
    try {
      console.log(bookingData);
      return this.bookingModel.create({ ...bookingData });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(
        null,
        'An error occured while creating your booking',
      );
    }
  }

  async getAllBookings(
    status?: BookingStatusType,
    payment_status?: PaymentStatusType,
  ): Promise<CubeBookingModel[]> {
    try {
      console.log('Model:', this.bookingModel);
      const bookings = await this.bookingModel.findAll();

      console.log(bookings);
      return bookings;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr....');
      console.error(error);
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(
        null,
        'Error while fetching bookings',
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The feature module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CubeService } from './services/cube.service';
import { CubeController } from './controllers/cube.controller';
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { CubeBookingModel } from './models/cube-booking.model';

@Module({
  imports: [SequelizeModule.forFeature([CubeBookingModel])],
  controllers: [CubeController],
  providers: [CubeService],
})
export class CubeModule {}
```

And the app.module.ts:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import { Module, CacheModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core';
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { ScheduleModule } from '@nestjs/schedule';

import { UserModule } from './components/users/user.module';
import { AuthModule } from './components/users/auth.module';

import { RolesGuard } from './roles/roles.guard';
import { EventsGateway } from './socket/events.gateway';

import { CubeModule } from './components/cube/cube.module';

const appEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false;

@Module({
  imports: [
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    BullModule.forRoot({
      redis: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: parseInt(process.env.REDIS_PORT, 10),
        password: '',
        connectTimeout: 5000,
        maxRetriesPerRequest: 1000000000,
      },
    }),
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      dialect: 'postgres',
      host: appEnv
        ? process.env.PRODUCTION_DATABASE_HOST
        : process.env.DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE_HOST,
      port: appEnv
        ? parseInt(process.env.PRODUCTION_DATABASE_PORT)
        : parseInt(process.env.DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE_PORT),
      username: appEnv
        ? process.env.PRODUCTION_DATABASE_USERNAME
        : process.env.DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE_USERNAME,
      password: appEnv
        ? process.env.PRODUCTION_DATABASE_PASSWORD
        : process.env.DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
      database: appEnv
        ? process.env.PRODUCTION_DATABASE_NAME
        : process.env.DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE_NAME,
      ssl: false,
      // logging: false,
      dialectOptions: {
        ssl: false,
      },
      autoLoadModels: true,
      synchronize: false,
    }),
    // Cache module
    CacheModule.register({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    CubeModule,
    UserModule,
    AuthModule,
    
    // Lots of other modules here
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: RolesGuard,
    },
    EventsGateway,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

As you can see, I've imported my model in the feature module and passed it to the `SequelizeModule.forFeature()` method. I've ran the migration as well, and the table is present in the DB. In fact, the `createBooking` service works fine, and creates the data which I can see in the DB. But when I try to fetch the data I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

And the error is coming from this line in services > getAllBookings:

```
const bookings = await this.bookingModel.findAll();
```

I don't get any compile-time error and everything checks out fine on the TS end. I've been on this for too long.

I saw these posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59776498/sequelize-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59776498/sequelize-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object) that look similar to my issue but I couldn't apply their suggestions to NestJS because my app.module.ts already looks fine.
Is there something I'm missing.

For context I'm using:
Node 18,
TS 4.3.5,
Nest 8.0
Sequelize 6.17.0
Sequelize CLI 6.4.

I've followed exactly what's in the [NestJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#sequelize-integration) but it still won't work.

Comment: Did you try to indicate some options in `findAll`?

Comment: No. I just used findAll() without options, which isn't supposed to be a problem

Comment: I meant to pass `{}` for example

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. Tried using the `where` clause, didn't work either.